# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE — не находит файл

Tags: mysql

Интересует сразу несколько вопросов:

1. файл берется с компа или сервера?
2. какой путь нужно писать?

Допустимо использование только с LOCAL.

Как бы я не писал путь к файлу

- C:\Users\Public\test.txt
- C:/Users/Public/test.txt
- с хостинга (корня) сайта `test.txt` или `./test.txt` или пишу полный путь сервера.

ничего не работает. Выдает постоянно, что файл не найден.

Но заметил одну странность, если напишу так

`LOAD DATA LOCAl INFILE '/robots/test.txt' INTO TABLE cat_a;` — идет долгая загрузка, но файл не найден (папку просто придумал)

`LOAD DATA LOCAl INFILE 'robots.txt' INTO TABLE cat_a;` — файл теперь найден, хотя на моем сайте его нет :)

Используется обычный хостинг. Что можете подсказать?

Comment: Вы документацию смотрели на load data local, в настройках сервера все для этого сделано ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html

Comment: на что конкретно нужно обратить внимание ?
Добавлю : файл /etc/passwd также открывается

Comment: *Как бы я не писал путь к файлу* Должно быть так: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Public\\test.txt'`.

Comment: да, так тоже писал . Все варианты из гугла опробовал и ничего :(